# Terminal output is slower than file write?

Tags: php

I wrote a small script to generate email addresses based on a pattern:

```
<?php
$host = '@gmail.com';
$prefix = 'email';
$total = 200000;

for($i = 0; $i <$total; $i++)
{
    echo $prefix . $i . $host . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Now, if I run this script as `$php generate.php` it takes around 15 seconds to complete the output echo. However, redirecting output (`$php generate.php > file`) completes within a second.

Is this something to do with PHP's buffering mechanism's or part of some Linux behavior?

Comment: if you run it directly in a terminal, the output has to be buffered and displayed. this will be the case with windows, linux, mac and every other system that has a console.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thought that much. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Linux that is causing the slowdown.  The same would happen if you printed the output in a windows console.  Each flush of the output is obliging the program to halt, the operating system to update its window, and the program to be given control to continue again.  If these flushes are numerous and often, it may indeed slow down things quite a bit.

Writing to a file still requires the operating system to step in, but there is no overhead beyond what you'd normally see with a program that reads and writes files.  That said, writing to the console is a handy tool for debugging a program and you should use it.  Just be sure that when it runs on the production machine, it writes to a file log instead.

Answer (score 2):

Printing to the console is always much slower on any operating system than writing to a file directly, because there are a lot more drivers and operating system operations the output data must go through.
File operations are heavily optimized (caching!), so it's always much faster than writing to any visual output device.

Comment: Thanks. I had a hunch this was the case, and also asked a few people in my office. But nobody could answer it, so I posted here. :D